# Crear en JS un div dentro de un section mediante una función

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero crear un función que vaya creando varios div dentro de un *section*. He logrado hacerlo, pero de esta manera no se le aplica una id automática y no se le aplican los elementos del CSS.

```
function addCapa() {
    var caja = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById('section').appendChild(caja);
}
```

Comment: que ID deberian tener los divs?

Comment: Deberían tener id="caja"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para darle un id debes sobrescribir la propiedad id del elemento

```
function addCapa() {
    var caja = document.createElement('div');
    caja.id = "caja"
    document.getElementById('section').appendChild(caja);
}
```

Comment: Es una mala práctica colocar mas de un ID con el mismo nombre en el documento, en todo caso deberías colocar clases, o colocar un correlativo a los IDs, Repito, en un documento HTML no puede ir mas de un ID con el mismo nombre

Comment: @Elboy no es que sea mala practica, sino que "no se debe hacer", si quisieras seleccionar un `div`, no podrias porque el `id debe ser unico`

Comment: @JuanRivera, dije que era una mala práctica porque muchos suelen hacerlo, al final aclaré, "no puede ir mas de un ID con el mismo nombre"

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con ustedes, si se va a llamar múltiples veces a la función lo mejor es hacerlo con clases, si el autor de la pregunta quiere puedo modificar la respuesta y poner un ejemplo con clases para evitar el conflictos con los id's